# NanoHTTPDを使ってバイナリの応答

Tags: android, nanohttpd

eclipseを使ってAndroidアプリを作っています。NanoHTTPD.javaを使ってhttpアクセスがあると、バイナリデータを応答するようにしたいと思っています。
assetsフォルダには"abc.bin"ファイル(バイナリデータ)があります。このファイルを応答したいのです。

```
private class MyHTTPD extends NanoHTTPD {
    public MyHTTPD() throws IOException {
        super(PORT, null);
    }
    @Override
    public Response serve(String uri, String method, Properties header,
            Properties parms, Properties files) {
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String key = "";

        try {
            try {
                is = getAssets().open("abc.bin");
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String str;
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    key += str;
                }
            } finally {
                if (is != null)
                    is.close();
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("test", "abc.binが読み込めません。");
        }
        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, MIME_DEFAULT_BINARY, key);
}
}
```

しかし、バイナリはそのまま配信されず変換されているようです。
Stringの変数にしているからでしょうか。またバイナリをhttp応答するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Stringに変換しているのはどんな意図があってでしょうか。

Comment: return new NanoHTTPD.Response()で返す三番目の引数がString型しか駄目なようなので、String型にしています。

Comment: `InputStream` を取る `Response()` もありますので、そちらを使うと良いかもしれません。

Comment: 蛇足とは思いますが、`finally` 内の `is.close()` を削除しておく必要があります。なお、`Response()` に指定した `InputStream` は `NanoHTTPD` の `HTTPSession.sendRequest()` メソッド内で `close` されています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

当てずっぽうですが `br.readLine()` で文字列に変換されてるように思えます。
加えてバイナリなのに1行読み込みというのも違和感があります。

[GitHub](https://github.com/elonen/nanohttpd/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java)のソースを見ると 3つ目に InputStream を受ける形があるので これを使えないでしょうか。

```java
    /**
     * Default constructor: response = HTTP_OK, mime = MIME_HTML and your supplied message
     */
    public Response(String msg) {
        this(Status.OK, MIME_HTML, msg);
    }

    /**
     * Basic constructor.
     */
    public Response(IStatus status, String mimeType, InputStream data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method that makes an InputStream out of given text.
     */
    public Response(IStatus status, String mimeType, String txt) {
        this.status = status;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
        try {
            this.data = txt != null ? new ByteArrayInputStream(txt.getBytes("UTF-8")) : null;
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            uee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

なので、`Response` のコンストラクタに `key` の代わりに `is` を渡して見て下さい。

```java
    return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, MIME_DEFAULT_BINARY, is);
```